# Bash script sudo and variables

Tags: bash

Totally new to Bash here, actually I've avoided it like a plague for 10 years. 
Today, there is no way around it.

After a few hours of beating my head against the keyboard, I discovered that sudo and any bash variable in a command gets stripped out.

So I have something like

somescript.sh

```
for i in {1..5}
do
    filename=somefilenumber"$i".txt
    echo $filename
done
```

on the command line now if I run it

```
user@deb:~$ ./somescript.sh
```

I get the expected

```
somefilenumber1.txt
somefilenumber2.txt
somefilenumber3.txt
somefilenumber4.txt
somefilenumber5.txt
```

but if I run with sudo, like
    user@deb:~$ sudo ./somescript.sh

I'll get this

```
somefilenumber{1..5}.txt
```

This is a huge problem because I'm trying to cp files and rm files in a loop with the variable.

So here is the code with cp and rm

```
for i in {1..10}
do
    filename=somefilenumber"$i".txt
    echo $filename
    cp "$filename" "someotherfilename.txt"
    rm "$filename"
done
```

I end up getting

```
cp: cannot stat 'somefilenumber{1..5}.txt': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove 'somefilenumber{1..5}.txt': No such file or directory
```

I need to run sudo also because of other programs that require it.

Is there any way around this?
Even if nothing else require sudo, and I don't use it, the rm command will prompt me for every file if I'm sure that I want to remove it or not. The whole point is to not be sitting here tied to the computer while it runs through hundreds of files.

Comment: Sure this is being run with bash, not `/bin/sh`? `{1..10}` is a bashism, so it's expected for `sh` not to expand it.

Comment: no i'm not sure. Actually now that you say it, I don't know the difference.

Comment: Make sure that the script is looking for the files in the right directory

Comment: Check that. Make sure your script starts with `#!/bin/bash` or `#!/usr/bin/env bash`, and that you didn't run it with `sh scriptname`.

Comment: @bwalshy, `{1..10}` isn't a glob -- unlike, say, `[0-9][0-9]`, it doesn't care if the files exist or not.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy okay I deleted the .sh from the scriptname. I put #!/bin/bash at the top of the script. Hmm. seems to work. I don't believe it though :D Will be throwing everything I got at it.

Comment: @user3474042, consider running your code through http://shellcheck.net/ for some extra automated feedback/assurance. :)

Comment: @user3474042 bash is a specific shell, with a number of added features (like `{1..10}`) that might or might not be available in other shells. `sh` is a generic name for ... well, whatever's included in your OS/distro/whatever as the default shell. It might be bash (with some features disabled for backward-compatibility) or dash (a much more basic shell) or zsh (another advanced shell with *different* features) or ksh or... almost anything. Basically, if you run a script with sh (either by the command `sh` or a `#!/bin/sh` shebang) you cannot count on having any bash extensions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to replace {1..10} with seq 1 10:

```
for i in `seq 1 10`
do
    filename=somefilenumber"$i".txt
    echo $filename
    cp "$filename" "someotherfilename.txt"
    rm "$filename"
done
```

Your problem sounds like the environment has something wrong for root, do you start the script with:
     #!/bin/bash
?

Comment: `seq` is not standardized command -- it's not part of bash itself, and it's not POSIX-specified. As such, it's not guaranteed to be available everywhere, and its usage in this manner is *also* dependent on the value of `IFS` -- if you'd set `IFS` to a non-default value, then your `for` loop would iterate only once, having all the numbers inside a single `$i`.

Comment: yea I tried seq on this machine, no go. It some distribution of debian that I am not really sure about. Not my system, I have to work in these constraints.

Comment: Correct that the problem is sh vs bash. As @CharlesDuffy and you mention, once I put #!/bin/bash in there, and remove the .sh from the script filename, it works fine. Thanks

Comment: seq  is a part of GNU coreutils, essential packages on debian and its derivatives. I have also some positive tests with arch, fedora, gentoo